# How to check redundant value using Bitwise AND and bitwise NOT Operator?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have got a below snippet of code to check the RAM redundant value using bitwise Operator

```
uint16 initial_value = (uint16)(myvalue_32bit & 0xFFFFu); 
uint16 toggle_value = ~((uint16)(myvalue_32bit >>16));

if(initial_value == toggle_value)
{
  print("correct value");
}
else
{
  print("false value");
}
```

I didn't understand what is happening in the first two lines of the code. Can somebody explain why the bitwise AND and bitwise NOT operator using here ? May be explanation with one example is helpful.

Comment: What's the definition of _"the RAM redundant value"_? I've never heard that before.

Comment: It's checking whether the high-order 16 bits are the bitwise complement of the low-order 16 bits.

Comment: @TomKarzes Yes, I can see what the code does but what makes this value redundant? I didn't get many hits when searching for it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Tom was answering OP’s question, not yours. For yours, the values are redundant because they contain the same information (in different forms).

Comment: This is a bad question for Stack Overflow, and here is why. Even if we take the position that all programming questions are on topic, even if they cover entirely plain elementary information in every textbook on C, we do not know how to answer this question because we do not know where to start. At the point in a textbook where `&`, `>>`, and `~` are discussed, students have been taught prerequisite information about bits and bytes and other things. When you post the question here, where are you starting from? Do you have that prerequisite information or do you need an answer from before that?

Comment: You have not given any information on where to start answering the question. Do you know what `0xFFFFu` is? Do you know what `&` is? Do you know what `uint16` is? Do you know what `(uint16)` is? Do you know what `>>` is? Do you know what `~` is? Is it some combination of these things that you do not understand? Which parts of the expressions do you understand, and which do you not understand? Have you read about these things in a textbook or tutorial yet?

Comment: @EricPostpischil _"Tom was answering OP"_ - Ah, ok :-) Can this type of redundancy be used for something practical? I did search for it but came up blank.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Error detection. If some communication noise corrupts a bit, this is likely to reveal it. And, due to the NOT, if something is methodically setting bits to zero or to one, it is likely to affect the two sets of bits “differently.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil Makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: @TedLyngmo We used to use this to detect simple cheat engine type hacking of values that really shouldn't be changed but might look similar to other values we don't really care about. I've also used it for saving a duplicate checksum value that uses a safer loading path if it appears the saved game has been modified.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I've created a similar schema myself with error correction of digial data in an analogue audio stream - but it just didn't occur to me right now. Also, the title got me on the wrong track. :-)

Comment: This might actually not be redundant information, for example, if `myvalue_32bit` is dereferencing a memory mapped IO location, or is reading the value of a hardware based register.

Comment: While it most certainly isn't the case here, it's important to give proper context `myvalue_32bit` isn't defined in your code. I'm mentioning this because with hardware registers and alike, it's not uncommon to see code that "appears" to be useless or doing something in an "inefficient" manner - but in those cases the unusual code is warranted by the fact that the code is interfacing with some real-time operating hardware (for example). This is also why IO access operations cannot be re-ordered by the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 32 bit value is constructed from two parts.

1. Lower 16 bits part.
2. Higher 16 bits parts having the value of the binary negated ***lower part***

- The `toggle_value` is taking the higher part as new 16 bits unsigned value, then binary negates it. As per p.2 it should has value of negated lower part, now it should have the same value as the lower part of your 32 bit value.
- `initial_value` is holding the lower part of the 32 bit value.

If they are equal it means that the the 32 bit value is correct (in understanding of this error check algorithm).